# Is CoreWCF supports KafkaBinding?

Tags: apache-kafka, wcf-binding, corewcf

Is CoreWCF supports KafkaBinding ? Is yes - Can someone please share the steps I need to follow in client side ? I could not able to find a way to create channel factory for Kafka Binding and make server calls ?

Channel factory should be created for Kafka binding and able to make server calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it supports **KafkaBinding**.

1.There is a package for it on **Nuget**

[CoreWCF.Kafka](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CoreWCF.Kafka/#dependencies-body-tab)

2.Binding generation and service injection can refer to the following code:

```
var binding = new KafkaBinding(KafkaDeliverySemantics.AtMostOnce)
{
    AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest,
    GroupId = "my-group"
};
var customBinding = new CustomBinding(binding);
KafkaTransportBindingElement transport = customBinding.Elements.Find<KafkaTransportBindingElement>();
transport.Debug = "all";

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
builder.Services.AddServiceModelServices().AddQueueTransport()

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseServiceModel(serviceBuilder => 
{
    services.AddService<Service>();
    services.AddServiceEndpoint<Service, IService>(new CoreWCF.Kafka.KafkaBinding
    {
        AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest,
        DeliverySemantics = KafkaDeliverySemantics.AtMostOnce,
        GroupId = "my-consumer-group"
    }, $"net.kafka://localhost:9092/my-topic");
});

CoreWCF.ServiceModel.Channels.KafkaBinding kafkaBinding = new();
var factory = new System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory<IService>(kafkaBinding,
    new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(new Uri($"net.kafka://localhost:9092/my-topic")));
IService channel = factory.CreateChannel();
await channel.CallServiceAsync(name);
```

Comment: Thank you so much !! This would help a lot